# Jquery getting everything inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to get everything from inside a p-tag.

Let's say the HTML code is this

```
<p>Hey everyone, this is it</p>
```

And JQUERY:

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
      ( $(this).html());
});
```

`This.html()` now contains the html inside the paragraph, OK good.

If I have `<p>Hey...<a href='something'>link</a></p>` everything is still available through `this.html()`. Or I could get the `<a>`-contents from this.children.

BUT if I have a `<div>` or a `<li>` or `<ul>` tags inside my `<p>`, `this.html()` does not contain the div or li or ul, and neither does this.children. This.html() stops before the  tag.

How do I retrieve EVERYTHING from my `<p>`-tag no matter what tags are in there?

Comment: That would be invalid html. Paragraph tags can only have inline elements as children, that is why it does not work.

Comment: There should not be a div nor a ul inside a p... Line-level elements like a and span are allowed tho, that's why you get those

Comment: If there is a <div> inside your paragraph, your paragraph is no longer a paragraph.

Comment: Have you tried $(this).contents()

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to use `<div>` tag instead of `<p>`. Then you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a `div` inside a `p`, the browser automatically ends the paragraph and starts a division. It is as if instead of `<div>`, ther was `</p></div>`. The same happens if you start a new paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah wrap everything in a div rather than `<p>`
`<p>` can only have certain elements in it such as links, strong, bold, spans
`<div>` can contain anything and is also a block level element